# Get the first displayed row of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

can anyone tell me how I can get the first displayed row on a datagridview?. I need to get  the first row whenever the user scrolls on the datagridview, whether the user has selected the row or not.

Can anyone tell me if this can be done?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property.
*And make sure all rows have the same height.*

Answer (score 0):

you can try this : datagridview.rows[0];